# Why is this returning a System.IO.IOException (Sharing violation on path /Storage.txt)?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {
        Console.Clear();
        string[] GQ = GenerateQuestions(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < GQ.Length; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i+1}. {GQ[i]}");
        }
    }
    public static string[] GenerateQuestions(int Quantity) {
        List<string> Lines = new List<string>();
        string Line;
        StreamReader SR = new StreamReader("Storage.txt");
        Line = SR.ReadLine();
        Lines.Add(Line);
        while (Line != null) {
            Line = SR.ReadLine();
            Lines.Add(Line);
        }
        SR.Close();
        SR = null;
        Lines.RemoveAt(Lines.Count - 1);
        int[] SI = SelectedIndexes(Quantity, Lines.Count);
        string[] SelectedLines = new string[Quantity];
        for (int j = 0; j < Quantity; j++) {
            SelectedLines[j] = Lines[SI[j]];
        }
        RemoveDBEntries(SI, Lines);
        return SelectedLines;
    }
    public static int[] SelectedIndexes(int Quantity, int Length) {
        Random R = new Random();
        List<int> Returns = new List<int>();
        int num;
        while (Returns.Count < Quantity) {
            num = R.Next(0, Length);
            if (!Returns.Contains(num)) Returns.Add(num);
        }
        return Returns.ToArray();
    }
    public static void RemoveDBEntries(int[] EntriesToBeDeleted, List<string> Lines) {
        File.Delete("Storage.txt");
        File.Create("Storage.txt");
        EntriesToBeDeleted = EntriesToBeDeleted.OrderByDescending(f => f).ToArray();
        foreach (int _i in EntriesToBeDeleted) {
            Lines.RemoveAt(_i);
        }
        StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter("Storage.txt");
        foreach (string _s in Lines.ToArray()) {
            SW.WriteLine(_s);
        }
        SW.Close();
    }
}
```

The file `Storage.txt` is already created and I populated it with some lines of random letters.
If there's nothing in the file to begin with it doesn't return an error, but it also doesn't do its intended function.
Both the StreamReader and StreamWriter are closed immediately after they're used
And the GenerateQuestions and SelectedIndexes functions work properly. It only breaks once I added the RemoveDBEntries function.
Apologies if this is stupid or similar, I'm quite new to programming.

EDIT
Jehof asked, so here's the full exception:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.IOException: Sharing violation on path /home/runner/RandomQuestionPicker/Storage.txt
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0019e] in <a17fa1457c5d44f2885ac746c1764ea5>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x00000] in <a17fa1457c5d44f2885ac746c1764ea5>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int,System.IO.FileOptions)
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, System.Boolean append, System.Text.Encoding encoding, System.Int32 bufferSize) [0x00055] in <a17fa1457c5d44f2885ac746c1764ea5>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path) [0x00008] in <a17fa1457c5d44f2885ac746c1764ea5>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(string)
  at MainClass.RemoveDBEntries (System.Int32[] EntriesToBeDeleted, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] Lines) [0x00060] in <1dc8387fbc014617ad20621352fb6414>:0 
  at MainClass.GenerateQuestions (System.Int32 Quantity) [0x00088] in <1dc8387fbc014617ad20621352fb6414>:0 
  at MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00005] in <1dc8387fbc014617ad20621352fb6414>:0
```

Comment: Pleased share details of the exception that is thrown

Comment: It would generally be better to wrap your stream in a `using` as in the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-read-text-from-a-file More about `using` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement